# Automatic Deployment of ASP.Net MVC using TFS2010 Beta2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automated-deploy

i am building an Asp.NET MVC web site, and i want to make the deployment to IIS automatically as part of the build process, as indicated in the title, i am using vs2010 beta2 with tfs2010 beta2, and the dev server is running widows server 2008 service pack2, wich means IIS 7.
so can anyone provide with set-by-step way on how to do that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't cover anything specific for TFS, but it's a good start at setting up Web Deploy:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx